# MLR 3 Learners contains 5 learner only?

Tags: r, mlr3

I am learning new MLR environment using MLR3

Compared to MLR, I can get the learners list using:

```
library(mlr)
ListLearners()
```

in MLR3, I get the learners list using:

```
library(mlr3)
mlr_learners
<DictionaryLearner> with 5 stored values
Keys: classif.debug, classif.featureless, classif.rpart, regr.featureless,
  regr.rpart
```

My Question is, does MLR3 only provide these 5 unique learners?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install and load the mlr3learners package for more regression and classification learners. The dictionary `mlr_learners` will automatically get populated. You can install even more learners from GitHub, see https://github.com/mlr3learners/mlr3learners.drat.